# Reset the user password. Is this principle ok?

Tags: cryptography, sails.js

I have implemented password reset for my site. Would you be so kind to point out eventual problems or silly things I have done.

Server is on separate location then the client. Server is Sails (node.js), while client is Angular and DB is postgresql.

1. User wants to change his password. He types his emails where the password will be sent to him. Captcha is here.
2. Server will first check is there such email. If so then it will....
3. Generate GUID (UUID library for node). Write that GUID in the database, with the user email (maybe user id as well). SO simple table with GUID, email and time stamp.
4. After that is done, the server will create a link, with this type. //localhost://changepwd?tokenizer=GUID
5. When user click the link GUID will be taken from the URL and compared to the one in the database. If it exists, then another check will be made to ensure that request is not over 1 hour (or whatever time).
6. After that user will be generated small form and sent to him. That form has fields to allow for a password change.
7. GUID will be embeded as a secret field in the form as well, and when the user submits the form final check against that GUID will be made.

There is much more going on here then I wrote down, but in essence this is my way of doing it. Any comment is more then appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

GUID is not a good token for password reset link, as it is often time-based and so it is predictable.

You should use something unpredictable, for example:

```
select md5("some_secret_phrase"||uuid_generate()||old_password_hash);
```

Comment: what is wrong with it exactly? (an attacker can anyway put the e-mail address in the form and generate new token)

Comment: When an attacker would be able to predict a token he would be able to reset a password of a victim even if he didn't receive password reset e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly valid flow. For additional security often a security question is asked - this stops a user who has compromised an email account from spreading more damage.